# Integral orthogonal group generated by unipotent elements?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, lie-groups, quadratic-forms

Suppose that $Q$ is a non-definite quadratic form on at least three variables with integer coefficients, for example $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$. Let us define for a ring $R$ the group $$SO(Q)(R)= \{ \gamma \in \operatorname{SL}_d(R) \text{ }| \text{ } Q\circ \gamma=Q \}$$ special orthogonal group of this quadratic form.

**Question:** Is $SO(Q)(\mathbb{Z})$ generated by unipotent matrices?

I know this is true for $SO(Q)(\mathbb{R})$ and also for $SO(Q)(\mathbb{Z})$ for the example given above.

Comment: recommend Noneuclidean Tesselations and their Groups by Wilhelm Magnus. They repeat some of the calculations of groups that were originally in Fricke and Klein (1897) .Magnus, mostly pages 123-130 for ternary.

Comment: well, why not. The main tool is to consider the group of $y^2 - zx,$ which is a copy of the modular group,  back on page 23